# request.js fails where CURL succeeds for GET request with Authorization header

Tags: node.js, curl, https, requestjs

I can make a GET request with an Authorization header from `curl` but not from `request` or `https` in Node.js.  The server returns status 200 with curl but 500 with `request` or `https`.  How might the call from `request`  or `https` be different from `curl`?  How might the server be reading them differently?

The following cURL succeeds from command line:

```
curl -H "Authorization:  Bearer abc123def456" https://api.domain.com/path/to/resource
```

But the same request fails with request.js in Node

```
var options = {
  type: 'get',
  url: "https://api.domain.com/path/to/resource",
  headers: {
     "Authorization": " Bearer abc123def456" 
  }
}
request(options, function (err, response, body) {
  assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200) ; // 500 internal error
})
```

The following also fails with request.js using the `auth` option:

```
var options = {
  type: 'get',
  url: "https://api.domain.com/path/to/resource",
  auth: {
    "bearer": "abc123def456" 
  }
}
request(options, function (err, response, body) {
  assert.equal(response.statusCode, 200) ; // 500 internal error
})
```

It also fails when using `https` without `request.js`:

```
var options = {
  host: 'api.domain.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/path/to/info',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": " Bearer abc123def456"
  }
}
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('end', function () {
    assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200) // 500 internal error
  })
});

req.on('error', function (e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.end();
```

But the curl requests succeeds if shelled out from Node:

```
exec("curl -H "Authorization:  Bearer abc123def456" https://api.domain.com/path/to/resource", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(stdout) // successfully retrieved and parsed
});
```

`request-debug` gives the following info:

```
{ request: 
   { debugId: 1,
     uri: 'https://api.domain.com/path/to/resource',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: 
      { host: 'api.domain.com',
        authorization: 'Bearer abc123def456' } } }
```

Comment: 500 internal error generally means there is an error at the server side. Did you check the API server logs? Is it trying to parse the 'User-Agent' header?

Comment: Great question. I don't have access to the server, just the OAuth route.  Does curl or request pass a `User-Agent` header?

Comment: Curl passes one, I don't think request does unless you specify it.

Comment: @NehalJWani  Thank you!! That was the clue I needed.  curl supplies additional  headers.  Adding `--verbose` to curl, I see one of these is `"Accept: */*"` and adding that to request makes it work.  Just for fun and formality please write that as an answer I can accept.

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[500 internal error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_error) generally means there is an error at the server side . So, ideally, you should be taking a look at the server logs.

However, if you don't have access to those logs, look at the difference between the requests sent by each one of the options you tried:

Module: Request (with manually specified auth header):

```
GET /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
Authorization:  Bearer abc123def456
host: api.domain.com
```

Module: Request (with explicitly specified auth header):

```
GET /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
host: api.domain.com
authorization: Bearer abc123def456
```

Module: HTTP (with manually specified auth header):

```
GET /path/to/info HTTP/1.1
Authorization:  Bearer abc123def456
Host: api.domain.com
```

Curl:

```
GET /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
Host: api.domain.com
User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
Accept: */*
Authorization:  Bearer abc123def456
```

It is quite evident that the rest of the modules do not send the [HTTP headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields) 'User-Agent' and 'Accept'. So, it could be the case that the app running on the server is trying to parse at least one of this and failing.